# C++ Memory leaks vectors(?)

Tags: c++, stdvector

In C++, the importance of deallocating memory when the program is either exiting or no longer serves a purpose is important. So if this is allocation of a dynamic array

```
char** dynamicArr = nullptr;

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    mapPtr[i] = new char[y];
}
```

and this is deallocation of a dynamic array

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        delete[] mapPtr[i];
}

delete[] mapPtr;
```

However, when it comes to vectors, I noticed that my global vector with 0 elements inside seems to be causing some memory leaks.

I've read up on this [link](http://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/68976/), a user commented that

> No. The std::vector will automatically de-allocate the memory it uses

Screenshot of my debugging.

[image: possible vector mem leak]

I have also tried these [steps](https://www.techiedelight.com/delete-vector-free-memory-cpp/) to clear the vector as well as make sure the vector inside the struct citySummInfo has shrunk to fit and clear hopefully not getting any memory leak but to no avail. Is there any way that I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Please edit to inline text, rather than posting pictures of it.

Comment: `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` should be called at the point in the program where you want to see what is remaining on the heap. Since your vectors are statically allocated, they will not have been destroyed at the time you call this function.

Comment: I think it is worth repeating lifetime of local and global variables.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtdumpmemoryleaks?view=msvc-170) says you can call `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);` which will do the memory check at program termination. I believe that should be after global variables are destroyed? I'm not sure on this point.

Comment: The implementation of `vector` you're using comes from your STL, so you might want to ask the vendor of your STL. But unless you're using some niche library that not many others are using, it is highly unlikely that your STL has memory leaks in such a common component.

Comment: You *may* be able to free the dynamic storage of `std::vector` by calling [`std::vector::shrink_to_fit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit), but this is at best a non-binding request, and the compiler is not required to actually free all of the vector's allocated memory.

Comment: Try to wrap the lines 45 till 49 with {} AND move this block into the `main` function, before the `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` call.

Answer (score 0):

As what @JohnFilleau have mentioned

> `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` should be called at the point in the program where you want to see what is remaining on the heap. Since your
> vectors are statically allocated, they will not have been destroyed at
> the time you call this function.

`_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` is meant to place right before the program terminates, and since my vectors are statically allocated, it has not been deallocated at the time when `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` has been called hence the "leaks".

Comment: You may also place the `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` call into your class' destructor (`struct dumper { ~dumper() { _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); } };`, for example) and place the following line `dumper d;` _before_ the line 45. So, the `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` will be called after destructing your verctor.